# How do I get notifications from desktop apps in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

In Windows 8, if a desktop app pops up a notification in the system tray, or flashes its title bar, I don't see any notification of this at all if I'm in a modern-style app! Is there any way to enable notifications for these events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible as this is a different environment, so the only solution is using a *sound* alert which you can hear despites being in the desktop. A lot of applications were warning you is critical have some way to play a sound, if they don't have that (in case of some kind of batch program (like converting media) you might be able to add a line in your batch script that plays a sound; for instance, with VLC player as that has command lines where you can shutdown VLC after you ran it. Otherwise you might just want to regularly check if you got a notification.

If you can get a second screen, that might be handy to put your desktop on while keeping the Modern UI on the other. Which solves your problem altogether if you can afford it.

Comment: Snap might also help in viewing both Desktop and Metro apps together, but of course is quite limited and won't help with other background apps.

Comment: Would it be possible, even in theory, to write an app that monitors the desktop and delivers notifications to the modern UI? Or are they completely segregated?

Comment: @ekolis: It's possible if you write both a desktop, modern UI and a service for talking between both.

Comment: Excellent! Guess I'll have to learn a bit about Windows 8 programming... :)